# Error in communication between containers with flask and postgres

Tags: docker, nginx, flask

I have a problem when trying to make the connection between containers using flask, nginx, and postgres. The following error appears:

```
flask       | sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused
flask       |   Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
flask       |   TCP/IP connections on port 5454?
flask       | could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
flask       |   Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
flask       |   TCP/IP connections on port 5454?
```

Flask connection:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:admin@localhost:5454/plataforma_testes'
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
    flask:
        build: ./flask
        container_name: flask
        restart: always
        environment: 
            - APP_NAME=PlataformDeTestes
            - DB_USERNAME=postgres
        expose:
            - 8080
        links:
            - database
        depends_on:
            - database

    nginx:
        build: ./nginx
        container_name: nginx
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "80:80"

    database:
        image: postgres:10
        env_file: postgres/.env
        ports:
          - "5454:5432"
        volumes:
          - /docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Change :

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:admin@localhost:5454/plataforma_testes'
```

to :

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:admin@database:5432/plataforma_testes'
```

`localhost` to `database` and port to `5432` then `docker-compose up` again

Comment: I made the suggested change but the problem persists

Comment: It also needs to be the standard database port 5432; `ports:` aren't considered (or required).

Comment: What @DavidMaze said worked, but now he has this error:

```
flask       | sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

But the User and Password are defined as "postgres" and "admin"

Answer (score 1):

Thank you! It worked using:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:admin@database:5432/plataforma_testes'
```

and

```
database:
 image: postgres:10
 env_file: postgres/.env
 volumes:
    - /docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```